# Robot framework : Database library keywords not getting executed

Tags: postgresql, robotframework

I recently started working with Robot framework. So I had a requirement where I needed to connect with Postgres db. 
So though I am able to connect with the db but then when I try to execute queries, the flow is getting stuck. Even the test is not failing. Following is what I did:

```
Connect To Database psycopg2 ${DBName} ${DBUser} ${DBPass} ${DBHost} ${DBPort}

${current_row_count} =  Row Count  Select * from xyz
```

The first statement is executing fine but then it gets stuck on second statement.
Can somebody help me out on this

Comment: Can you elaborate with what you mean with 'stuck'?

Comment: Basically I mean to say that code gets hanged while executing second command mentioned above.

Comment: Ok so I figured out the issue. I had bridged adapter setting on my virtual box., changing it to NAT solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To Execute Query and get data from result :

```
    Connect To Database    psycopg2    ${DBName}    ${DBUser}    ${DBPass}    ${DBHost}    ${DBPort}
    ${output} =    Query    SELECT * from xyz;
    Log    ${output}
    ${DataResults}=    Get from list    ${output}    0
    ${DataResults}=    Convert to list    ${DataResults}
    ${DataResults}=    Get from list    ${DataResults} 0
    ${DataResults}    convert to string   ${DataResults}
Disconnect From Database
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your query.... read below a bit documentation and an example ;)
In the example you can see example variable but introduce your data ;)

Name: Connect To Database Using Custom Params

Source: DatabaseLibrary

Arguments:
[ dbapiModuleName=None | db_connect_string= ]
Loads the DB API 2.0 module given `dbapiModuleName` then uses it to connect to the database using the map string `db_custom_param_string`.

Example usage Example usage: :

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymssql    database='${db_database}' , user='${db_user}', password='${db_password}', host='${db_host}'
${queryResults}    Query    ${query}
Disconnect From Database
```